# How to compile GTK wave viewer on Windows 7?

Tags: gtk, cygwin, mingw, vhdl, ghdl

For the installation and compilation of GTK wave viewer 3.3.35 on Windows 7, I downloaded Cygwin from http://www.cygwin.com/ and installed it. I also installed the MinGW and linked its make application with the Cygwin for compilation of the software on the windows as mentioned in the guide for GTK wave viewer 3.3.35.

I am able to **configure** GTK wave viewer through Cygwin  but the next step is to **make** and that is what is not happening in my case.
It says " missing seperator,stop"
I really do not know how to get rid of this error.
Plz help..

For your info I need Gtk wave viewer to run the GHW format files (gets generated after compiling and running VHDL files on GHDL) to **observe the Vhdl simualtion waveforms** of the VHDL codes.

Answer (score 1):

The "missing seperator,stop" error usually means the makefile generated isn't cygwin-happy/compatible.  Since you've minGW install, did you try compiling via minGW instead of Cygwin?  Is there a parameter in the configure script that you can use to configure GTKwave for platform/os cygwin that would generate a proper cygwin makefile?  Run "configure --help" to see what options are available for configure and if there is an option to configure the package for cygwin?

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin was able to build and run gtkwave for me. The exact permutation of packages to be selected in setup.exe took a few iterations, I selected the following:

`automake, gperf, gtk+, python-gtk2.0, tcl, tcl-tk, xeyes, xz, zlib-devel, libgtk2.0_0, pkg-config`

After setup completes launch: `Start` --> `Cygwin-X` --> `XWin Server` to start the X server. Then

```
$ wget http://gtkwave.sourceforge.net/gtkwave-3.3.45.tar.gz
$ tar -xzf gtkwave-3.3.45.tar.gz
$ cd gtkwave-3.3.45
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

To verify installation the gtkwave binary found in a cygin window should match

```
$ which gtkwave
/usr/local/bin/gtkwave
```